# Selenium Login validation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

We have 3000 Username and password. We need to test it against successful login of a webpage. The problem is that when found a successful login the page redirects to user account. again log out from the account and re entering username and password takes time. Is there a solution for this

Comment: You can try data driven test in the case.

Answer (score 2):

If its just going to be login validation, then I would recommend you to use `HtmlUnitDriver` which is used for headless automation.It will be somewhat faster compared to usual browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and Conquer

Split your list in 2-10 or more parts and run ist on differend maschines. You can also test to use moore than one thread on an multicore pc.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with security here, since you have to store the user/password pairs either in your java code, or a properties file, or the database (in cleartext, instead of hashed values).

I think that instead one should use at most one user per application role to test the authentication + authorization (these should be of course "test" users created specifically for your tests).